# Under gnome (from debian 6.0.7 Squeeze) my space acts like the PowerDown button

Tags: debian, gnome

I installed a debian squeeze on my computer and when I strike the spacebar under X11-gnome a window appears explaining that my computer is about to stop (within 60 secondes). Here I can cancel, hibernate, reboot or stop. It is acting just like if I press the Power-Down button on my computer.
How can I remove this behaviour ? It is a real handicap using the shell.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you happen to be using a non-standard keyboard or keyboard mapping?

Comment: Hi @Dan, Thank you for your answer. Well actually the keyboard is quiet standard : Hewlett Packard AZERTY (I am French). And this do not occurs when I am in console text mode (without X11).